# Calculating Total Overtime for the week

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

can someone help me, so I want to make a method that will calculate from the overtime list, the total hour for each week of the month.

```
readonly List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, TimeSpan>> overTimeList = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, TimeSpan>>();//the list of overtime hours, the data is printed below in the form of data {...}

DateTime start = new DateTime(calendar1.CurrentDate.Year, calendar1.CurrentDate.Month, 1); //start (beginning of month in calendar)
DateTime stop = new DateTime(calendar1.CurrentDate.Year, calendar1.CurrentDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);//end (end of calendar month)
var weeksOverTimeSum = WeeklyOverTime(start, stop); //This is how I call the method
//method in which I want to get a certain list
private List<SundayWithWeekSum> WeeklyOverTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate)
        {
            var w = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek - 1;
            var result = from q in overTimeList
                         where q.Key >= startDate && q.Key <= stopDate
                         group q by (q.Key.Date.Day + w) / 7 into g
                         select new SundayWithWeekSum { Day = g.FirstOrDefault().Key, Balance = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.Value.Ticks)) };
                        //group q by(q.Key.Date.Day + (w == 0 ? w - 1 : w - 2)) / 7 into g
                        //select new SundayWithWeekSum { Day = g.FirstOrDefault().Key, Balance = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.Value.Ticks)) };
            return result.ToList();
        }

    class SundayWithWeekSum
    {
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Balance { get; set; }
    }
```

i show this data in the calendar, i will consider the month of June, the list is overtime hours for days, I want the overTimeList for the whole month with

```
data {
[0]{6/3/2019, 00:12:00},
[1]{6/4/2019, -00:11:00},
[2]{6/5/2019, 00:13:00},
[3]{6/7/2019, 00:13:00},
[4]{6/8/2019, -00:14:00},
[5]{6/11/2019, -00:35:00},
[6]{6/12/2019, 00:15:00},
[7]{6/14/2019, -00:02:00},
[8]{6/15/2019, -01:20:00},
[9]{6/17/2019,  00:11:00},
[10]{6/18/2019, 00:08:00},
[11]{6/19/2019, 00:14:00},
[12]{6/21/2019, 00:14:00},
[13]{6/22/2019, -00:54:00},
[14]{6/24/2019, 00:20:00},
[15]{6/25/2019, 00:12:00},
[16]{6/26/2019, 00:12:00},
[0]{6/29/2019, 00:48:00}
}
```

So it's time to show the working time of the workers in the calendar, and now, as an input to the method, I assign start and stop for a specific month, and then I want to calculate the total amount of overtime for all weeks of the month. You finally get the SundayWithWeekSum list eg:

```
FirstWeek- 06/02/2019; +00.00, 
SecondWeek- 06/09/2019; 13.00, 
ThirdWeek- 16/06/2019; -1.47, 
FourthWeek- 06/23/2019; -00.27, 
FifthWeek- 06/30/2019; 1.12
```

This is an example of my code, I thought I was going through the month, and through every day, and to make a break when it was finished that Sunday I saved for every week (day) the total balance in the list "balanceForWeeks".

Thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of your input data (along with C# compilable code that defines the input)? And then how that input is transformed into the output? And then what that output would be?

Comment: @Enigmativity Input would be the date for that month to start, in the while loops of the loop where I go for every day of the month.
Then I thought I was going through a list of overtime (I already have overtime for each day), and I'm adding to the balance for all the days until it ends this week, and when it's over, I keep the total hours for that week and I enter the list . That would be enough for me.

Comment: You do not increment `CurrentDate` within the `while` loop.  So I think this is likely to just loop forever.  But I'm not 100% the reason for the two loops.

Comment: @Mara - Can you please provide the input in valid C# code? And then what the output should be. Right now the question is not detailed enough.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the help, I corrected my question (code), I entered the input start parameter, and in order to invite the method, if I received the result for each week of the month of the total hour of that week in the form of Sunday, 05:00, that would be great.

Comment: @Mara - Please provide the input in valid C# code.

Comment: @Mara - Please provide the expected output for the input.

Comment: @Enigmativity I corrected my question, I inserted the data from the list, and the data I want to get in the end

Comment: @Mara - Please can you make the input **valid C# code**? I should be able to copy, paste, and run your code. I want a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity I set up all the necessary information I mean, I have nothing more to forward to you, that's what I hope to do. You have input into the method, the data from the overtime list, and the desired output that I would like to get in the list.

Comment: @Enigmativity I do not think that the question should be asked with a negative one, I tried all the information to pass, of course, those that are important

Comment: @Enigmativity The application is itself required to have it with a little bit of code, paste and run as you say it started.

Comment: @Mara - What don't you understand about providing the input data as valid C# code? I want to copy, paste, and run your code. I can't so it make it hard to answer your question and it makes your question hard for future readers to understand.

Comment: @Enigmativity To tell you honestly, I do not know what else I can put in the code, to make it clearer to you, and to run as a test that part. I copied everything and gave it as an example that I think is relevant. So how do I start, stop month, start the month and end with the WeeklyOverTime method, and finally I just want to get a list of this type 06/02/2019; 00.00, 06/09/2019; 13.00, 16/06/2019; -1.47,  06/23/2019; -00.27, 06/30/2019; 1.12 please understand my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196739/discussion-between-mara-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick -

```
readonly List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, TimeSpan>> overTimeList = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, TimeSpan>>();
private List<SundayWithWeekSum> WeeklyOverTime(DateTime startDate, DateTime stopDate)
{
     var w = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek - 1;
     var result = from q in overTimeList
                  where q.Key >= startDate && q.Key <= stopDate
                  group q by (q.Key.Date.Day + w) / 7 into g
                  select new SundayWithWeekSum { Day = g.FirstOrDefault().Key, Balance = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(x => x.Value.Ticks)) };
    return result.ToList();
}
```

The above function will return `List<SundayWithWeekSum>`with week starting with Sunday and total duration of week. It includes start and end dates.

Let me know if I miss something.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help, this is good, just because it's a problem, I think the method from the first day of counting 7 next ones, there are weeks in which, for example, there are only 3 days until the end of the week, it means this for July, but for June we have only 1.2 by the end of the month, the method should always work break at the end of the week any, if you understand?

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to understand. Could you pleas provide couple of sample inputs and expected outputs. Including the ones having boundary conditions.

Comment: So it's time to show the working time of the workers in the calendar, and now, as an input to the method, I assign start and stop for a specific month, and then I want to calculate the total amount of overtime for all weeks of the month. You finally get the SundayWithWeekSum list
          eg:
          FirstWeek- 06/02/2019; +00.20,
          SecondWeek- 06/09/2019; -2.00,
          ThirdWeek- 16/06/2019; +00.05,
          FourthWeek- 06/23/2019; -02.00,
          FifthWeek- 06/30/2019; -04.00

Comment: It looks much better, thank you very much !!!
Is it possible to ask to link this to Sunday, I think it is this part => that every sunday is registered here (is it a balance for that week), and if the Balance is zero on Sunday to subscribe for that Sunday 0.

Comment: @Guarav, So for example, these data are entered for every first day of the week, I want it to be that Sunday with that sum, and if we observe, for example, the month of June, I have sunday in it right now; that if I do not have data to set 0 as Balance, the result of the whole query was 2/6/2019,0; 9/6/2019, -5; 16/6/2019, 10; 23/6/2019, -2; 30/6/2019, 3;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196717/discussion-between-gaurav-mathur-and-mara).